# Check java.util.date and MySql timestamp belong to same day

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

From Java, I have a Date object and how should I compare it with the Mysql timestamp to check whether it belongs to the same day?

```
select c.content, c.contentDate from Contents c where c.contentDate = ?1 and c.userName = ?2
```

The above sql should return records that belong to a particular day(Date). But, how to compare the Java Date and Sql Timestamp?

Comment: If `contentDate` a date only or a full time stamp with time of day?

Comment: content date in mysql is timestamp. I want to fetch records that belong to a particular Date by comparing it with the contentDate(timestamp) in the mysql.

Comment: If `contentDate` can be 2 AM or 9 PM of the given day, then you cannot use `contentDate = ?`, because there is no single value for a whole day. You need to say `contentDate >= ? and contentDate < ?`, where the first `?` is midnight at the beginning of the day, and the second `?` is midnight at the beginning of the following day. You calculate those two values in Java (e.g. using `Calendar` or `LocalDate`), then use `setDate()` on the `PreparedStatement` to set the values.

Comment: Content date in mysql: 2016-04-29 00:19:46
Data that has to be given in the the where condition Fri Apr 29 00:00:00 CDT 2016. 

How do I retrieve the records where contentDate falls on the day Fri Apr 29 00:00:00 CDT 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `contentDate` can be 2 AM or 9 PM of the given day, then you cannot use `contentDate = ?`, because there is no single value for a whole day. You need to say `contentDate >= ? and contentDate < ?`, where the first `?` is midnight at the beginning of the day, and the second `?` is midnight at the beginning of the following day. You calculate those two values in Java (e.g. using `Calendar` or `LocalDate`), then use `setDate()` on the `PreparedStatement` to set the values.

```
LocalDate easter = LocalDate.of(2016, Month.MARCH, 27);

// Get all content from Easter Day (Mar 27, 2016)
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Contents WHERE contentDate >= ? and contentDate < ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(easter));
    stmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(easter.plusDays(1)));
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            //code here
        }
    }
}
```